# Docker certified containers on Docker CE

Tags: docker, docker-container

I'm not sure if I am allowed use Docker certified containers on Docker CE for development & production.

> Docker Certified Infrastructure, Containers and Plugins are **exclusively** available for Docker EE with cooperative support from Docker and the Certified Technology Partner. *From: https://www.docker.com/enterprise-edition*

I tried to run [microsoft/nanoserver](https://store.docker.com/images/nanoserver) on CE and didn't get any errors/warnings. Therefore I suspect that I can use them on CE for both development & production purposes?

Can someone explain this a little better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`community/Docker-Technology-Partner-Program-Guide.pdf`](https://www.docker.com/sites/default/files/community/Docker-Technology-Partner-Program-Guide-082517.pdf) is a bit more precise:

> Content that runs on a current version of Docker Enterprise Edition Basic may be published in the Docker Store and is eligible to 
>   become a Docker Certified container or plugin's.
>
> Content that requires the Docker Community Edition may be published in the Docker Store, but can neither be certified nor 
>   supported by Docker.  However, the vendor, in this case, has the option to provide support for such content

In the case of [nano-server image](https://store.docker.com/images/nanoserver), being certified does *not* mean you would *have to* run it in Docker EE only.
It only means it does not *require* docker CE: you can run it on docker CE, but CE is not *required*.
However, if you run it on Docker EE, then the certification means, a subscribed in [Trusted and Certified](https://www.docker.com/enterprise-edition), that the *certified* container does:

> provide trusted ISV products packaged and distributed as Docker containers - built with secure best practices cooperative support.